# visit post page by writing meta field value in the url

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type named poll. When a poll is created it is given a unite integer value which is saved as post meta "poll_id". This is the id i want to present in the frontend as well as in the url when viewing polls. I want an url such as mysite.com/?poll=21 to lead to the poll that has the poll_id meta value of 21.

My setup is a blank theme (does nothing) and this is the code that is in my plugin to handle the templates and queries:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', function ($post_link, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type === 'poll') {
        $poll_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'poll_id', true);
        if ($poll_id) {
            error_log('post_type_link: ' . $poll_id);
            return add_query_arg('poll', $poll_id, home_url());
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}, 10, 2);

add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && isset($query->query_vars['poll'])) {
        $poll_id = intval($query->query_vars['poll']);
        
        $query->set('post_type', 'poll');
        $query->set('post_status', 'any');
        $query->set('meta_key', 'poll_id');
        $query->set('meta_value', $poll_id);
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
    }
});

add_filter('query_vars', function ($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'poll';
    return $vars;
}, 10, 1);

add_filter('template_include', function ($template): string {
    if (get_query_var('name') === 'create-poll' || get_query_var(DAOPLUG) === 'create-poll') {
        return DAOPLUG_PATH . 'templates/create-poll.php';
    } elseif (get_query_var('poll')) {
        return DAOPLUG_PATH . 'templates/single-poll.php';
    } elseif (is_home()) {
        return DAOPLUG_PATH . 'templates/home.php';
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        return DAOPLUG_PATH . 'templates/page.php';
    } elseif (is_single() ) {
        return DAOPLUG_PATH . 'templates/single.php';
    } else {
        return DAOPLUG_PATH . 'templates/404.php';
    }

    return $template;
}, PHP_INT_MAX);
```

The problem is that have_posts() does not return anything inside single-poll.php and so i can not access the post data in the markup. I'm also very unsure if this is the way to do it or if it is doable at all.